# Hibernate column alias generation problem

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, alias

my customer has a kind of interesting Filemaker database which I try to use with spring boot + jpa + hibernate. In most cases it works quite well but the database has some really bad style column names which break the sql using bad characters as alias names...
I got a column in the database with german umlaut in it...

```
    @Entity(name = "com.bic.ts.db.JPAMitarbeiter")
    @Table(name="Mitarbeiter SB")
    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class JPAMitarbeiter {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id_Mitarbeiter", nullable = false)
        private long idMitarbeiter;
    
        @Column(name = "web_email")
        private String eMailAdresse;
    
        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;
    
        @Column(name = "Abkürzungen Name")
        private String kuerzel;
    }
```

The jpa / hibernate mapping uses some kind of algorithm to create the alias names within the default queries I use from an JpaRepository for accessing the tables.

If I do a repo.findAll() I got the following sql generated by hibernate:

```
select
    jpamitarbe0_."id_mitarbeiter" as id_mitar1_2_,
    jpamitarbe0_."web_email" as web_emai2_2_,
    jpamitarbe0_."abkürzungen name" as abkürzun3_2_,
    jpamitarbe0_."name" as name4_2_ 
from
    "caos mitarbeiter sb" jpamitarbe0_
```

The "ü" within the as clause "as abkürzun3_2_" breaks the query... If I remove the column everything works as expected...

During debugging I came across the possibility in hibernate to define a result-set mapping (see DefaultEntityAliases in hibernate) but I found no way to hand this mapping through my framework stack...

I thought about adding a custom dialect but did not find a way to modify the alias.

I tried to use a custom StatementInspector to modify the sql... did not work either...

I tried to fiddle with @ColumnTransformer and @FieldResults and @SqlResultSetMapping but I failed...

Isn't there a kind of simple way to tell hibernate to use a custom alias for a special field?

Just having an "alias" property within the @Column annotation would be my preferred solution but this does not exist...

Any help really welcome :-)

Best regards
Stefan

Comment: Have possibly looked at UTF8 related configuration options for hibernate?

 <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>

also see this:

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2482094

Comment: Did not help anything... I already have a switch to tell the jdbc driver to use UTF-8, otherwise the FIELD can't get found. If I run the sql statement just with eleminating the 'ü'  in the alias "akrzun3_2_" everything works like a charm... so UTF-8 is not the problem here imho...

Comment: I just go an answer on the claris community supporting the jdbc driver... using quotes ("") around the alias will help... But I have no idea either how to get this done using hibernate...

Comment: Might be worth turning the SQL logging on and see what it is generating, it might already be quoted.

Comment: The above SQL statement was copied from the hibernate log... so the generated sql has quotes on the field names but not on the alias.... The alias class in hibernate has some methods to UNQUOTE the alias... but that's exactly what I do NOT want :-)

Comment: I am not sure, from what I am seeing setting the flag in the config should be all you need to do. There are some people that suggest turning on UTF-8 encoding on the database itself, but because you already have a column name with a unicode character, I am thinking that is already turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I did already spend hours on this topic and I decided to do it the really ugly way... I recreated the Alias.java class from hibernate in the same package as the original class and hard-coded the quotes to the alias generation... (I changed the toAliasString method to return each alias with quotes)...

Now everything works as expected... I know that it's a really bad idea but it should work as long as I don't change the hibernate version I am using...

So yes, this works... but NO, it should not be considered as a useful answer...

A simple switch or setting in hibernate to allow aliases with quotes would definitely be a nicer approach... or to be able to put these kind of things into the hibernate dialect...

But I got to go on with other stuff... Thanks for all your help out there...

For anyone interested in the topic: I found an old thread (2016) in the hibernate forums with exactly the problem: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10493

Best regards
Stefan

Comment: Although not very helpful for you right now, with Hibernate 6.0 this will not be a problem anymore because we don't use aliases anymore and instead rely on the select item position directly.

Comment: Good to know... is there some release date...? :-)

Comment: We plan to release a final version by the end of the year.

Comment: Very cool, thanks a lot... hope that spring boot will soon integrate the new version :-)

Comment: @ChristianBeikov, is it possible to apply select item position logic directly in hibernate 3? Would it be relatively simple?

Comment: No, Hibernate had to change the whole type system and query translation to support positional selects. That is nothing that can be easily done.